# f:convertDateTime converter error

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am trying to enter a time by using `<f:convertDateTime>` tag. Without this tag, I can enter without problem as a text but when I add the line below, I get the error inside the library when I click and try to enter a digit to field.

```
<h:inputText
    required="true"
    styleClass="inputTypeDatePicker" id="cfTransactionTimeInput"
    value = "#{mybean.cfTransactionTime}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="time" timeStyle="short" />
    <hx:inputHelperAssist id="assist1" promptCharacter=""
         errorClass="inputText_Error" />
    <f:attribute name="fieldRef" value="Input" />
</h:inputText>
```

> Error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined" in hx client core.

Do you have any idea what is the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your value is undefined. Show more code.

Comment: Where are you using thf `f:convertDateTime` tag? Can you show the code where it is?

Comment: I just added the part of defination

Comment: remove this spaces in between : `value = #{mybean.cfTransactionTime}` to `value=#{mybean.cfTransactionTime}` on the `<h:inputText`

Comment: @JorgeCampos : Removing those spaces is not needed but there is a missing opening quote `"` in the same line but I assume it is a typographical error. It should go like this `value = "#{mybean.cfTransactionTime}"` instead.

Comment: You are right @tiny I think that it is not. It is really missing. Thanks

Comment: Sorry guys there is already " just I did not take it while copiying line.

Comment: The error is somewhere in the generated HTML/JavaScript code and/or some JavaScript code of your own you may be using somewhere. You are the only one who may be supposed to debug the cause of the error.

Comment: Reading the error and seeing your code, my guess is that is related with a missing attribute on the tag `<hx:inputHelperAssist id="assist1" promptCharacter="" errorClass="inputText_Error" />` Change it to `<hx:inputHelperAssist id="assist1" promptCharacter="" errorClass="inputText_Error"  length="10"/>` Just to test. You will need to see the docs of this tag if it is the case.

Comment: I saw an answer of BalusC in another forum regarding the use of `hx:inputHelperAssist` that "The problem with this IBM component library is that it is closed source and that its documentation is only available when you have paid for it (it is included in WSAD/RAD help menu)", so maybe it's some configuratio issue with your hx:inputHelperAssist Tag. Meanwhile, I saw many people using `promptCharacter="*"` I don't know why, but if you have the documentation and you can try it maybe that will help

Comment: I tried to add length attribute but it is not defined. When you put prompt as * it puts ** ** to the time field when it is rendered. It is hard to find specification for this therefore I still could not solve the problem.